# Android httpcore, httpmime and httpclient-android libraries import givs an error

Tags: java, android, http

In my **Android** I'm to **upload** a file to a back-end server and thought of doing it using **HTTP post request using MultipartEntity**. In this case I first added **httpcore** and **httpmime** libraries and it gave me a error. so after some googling I found that **httpclient-android** too have to import. so finally my **build.gradle** file is looks like below.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.m.l"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 69
        versionName '2.0.15'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':holoColorPickermaster')
    compile project(':qRCodeReaderViewlib')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
}
```

but now when I'm running the app it prompts me with different error.my error log is as below,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/concurrent/BasicFuture.class
```

i look for this error in the web and and try to fix it. but got no proper solution. found that this was a caused by **duplication** of files. how can I fix this. thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some sources that you don't want to be compiled, you have to declare a filter for the sources, not for the class files that are put in the Jar. Something like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            include 'com/ourcompany/somepackage/activityadapter/**'
            include 'com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/**'
            exclude 'com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/polling/**'
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is valid if you don´t want to compile these packages, but if you want to compile them and exclude from your JAR you could use

```
jar {
    exclude('mi/package/excluded/**')   
    exclude('mi/package/excluded2/**')  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. in my case it says "duplicate entry: org/apache/http/concurrent/BasicFuture.class" in the error. how can I find which to be exclude as far as they belongs to libraries ???????